# how to get the subnet mask of domain

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ip

I'm trying to get a specific domain subnet mask.
I managed to get it's IP using 2 different ways:

```
JHSoftware.DnsClient.LookupHost(_hostName);
Dns.GetHostAddresses(_hostName);
```

Now I want to calculate the IP range, but to do so, I need the subnet mask.
I don't know how to get the subnet mask.
Is there a way?

Thanks in advance!

Shaul

Comment: A DNS domain doesn't have a subnet mask.

Comment: So how can I know the rang of IP's belongs to the host?

Comment: You can't, bar logging in to the machine that has the given IP address and checking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, the mask is not advertised it is a filter that enables the network stack to interpret which IPs it can talk to.

It is possible to use software to estimate the subnet mask based on common masks and the range of observed IP addresses.

Comment: all you can do with those estimates is to establish a _lower bound_ on the network size.

Comment: pretty impressive resume you've got there